# What is the easiest way to remove the old grout?

Tags: tile

I am going to regrout the tile in the bath/shower area.  What is the easiest way to remove the old grout?

Comment: Jackhammer works great.

Answer (score 12):

## **Easiest:**

[image: C4]

## **Easy:**

A rotary tool (e.g. Dremel) with a grout removal bit:

[image: Rotary tool]

## **Also Easy:**

An oscillating multi-tool with a grout bit:

[image: Oscillating multi-tool]

## **Least easy:**

A grout saw:

[image: Grout saw]

## **Downright Painful:**

Dr. Pickems approach:

[image: Dental tools]

Comment: The new style ultrasonic saws have nice grout removal blades.  I use a SonicCrafter by Rockwell  See:  www.rockwelltools.com/en-US/SC-Hyperlock-RK5140K.aspx?gclid=CMz2woGp1rUCFY6e4AodWREAXw

Comment: oscillating multitools usually have a grout bit that works well.

Comment: Dremel has 2 grout bits, 1/8 and 1/16.  The 1/16 is very delicate and breakable with side pressure, so go very lightly, if you need to use it for tightly spaced joints.

Comment: Unless your God, I think the C4 would damage the tiles (and the house). +1 for the laugh and an answer!

Comment: @Monso Yes, blowing up your home is an unfortunate side effect, but the grout would be "removed." :)

Comment: Sorry to hijack your answer but I could not resist. Feel free to edit it back off.

Comment: What about using a reciprocating saw with a grout removal bit?

Answer (score 2):

Ok... this question asked easiest. (And also a method that I have successfully used).

Get a good quality breathing mask, stainless steel wire brush, some gloves and some pool acid (Hydrochloric Acid)

If you have normal tiles (porcelain or ceramic) you can simply pour the acid onto the shower floor... will eat away the grout in no time.  I would also use small amounts at a time so that you are not overwhelmed by the noxious gasses.

Please ensure that you have made your bathroom well ventilated at all times.

Wash away the small portion of acid with water after every application.

Comment: This doesn't sound very safe, even compared to the C4...

Comment: OP didn't ask for safest. He asked for easiest. :)