# Removing cracked grout without damaging tile and granite

Tags: grout

[image]
How and what tools would I need to remove grout without damaging the tile backsplash and granite countertop. The cabinet has settled and crack appears on the whole length of the countertop was installed 10 yrs ago.

Comment: Is there a method which you've seen which you have a specific question about? Does searching  for "how to remove grout" in Google not return anything relevant?

Comment: Another option would be to just caulk over it with a matching sanded caulk. It should have been caulked to start with  so removing some with a grout saw or oscilatting tool with would be best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to remove the old grout?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-old-grout)

Answer (score 1):

No tool.

Since the grout has not broken and just has a crack, it would be more appropriate to add a thin bead of caulk over this section (silicone or matching latex).

You can take the grout out and regrout, however it will crack again.

I prefer grouting - and then caulking later after cracking - in these areas.   The reason is with a larger gap you have to apply more caulk and it fails quicker and harder to maintain.   It might seem like why grout and have it fail.   Well because it takes 20 seconds to grout it and cracking isn't really a failure for a backsplash... more cosmetic.

Comment: I do agree but have not had as many issues with modified grout or epoxy based maybe I have been lucky but a thin bead is better.

Comment: @EdBeal - if you see vertical cracks that is failure and you remove the grout.   Simply no reason to remove it when the answer is to add caulk.   By leaving it you just add less caulk (and less work is a bonus).